# Have any of you applied TDD in VHDL?

Tags: tdd, vhdl, fpga

I applied TDD for software development, and it was really good! Now, I'm keen on FPGA design with VHDL and I am wondering about how to apply TDD methodology with it.

Have any of you used TDD on FPGA design? If yes, how do yo do? Do you know any articles or materials to learn about?

Thanks!

Comment: VUnit is one. (following JUnit for Java, AUnit for Ada etc). It also ties in with OSVVM to give constrained random etc, without the need for other oddball test languages, UVM etc. http://vunit.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never specifically applied TDD, but I always have testbenches for the design components in VHDL projects.

Although it is not entirely within the philosophy of TDD, a lot of hardware design end up resembling some of its description. In fact, I would argue that hardware is often much more suitable for testing with fine granularity, because components often have clearly defined inputs and outputs where software units would be depending on many other classes for the functionality to make sense.

The resemblance is strong where all sub-blocks are being properly verified, especially if you consider the blocks to be 'features'. Even more so, when using stimuli files for testbenches on small arithmetic blocks, it is normal to first start with some common and special cases you can think of, and then add more as you find problems in your high-level tests. You will end up working iteratively on a fairly low level.

Some concepts of TDD that don't map well to hardware design include the idea of 'user stories'. Unless if you have specifically designed your project to be extensible, it is more likely you won't see any top level tests passing until all your components are in place.

I don't have any specific links or materials for you. Usually there are many custom scripts involved for running all the tests.  Apart from testbenches it often involves checks with assertions, equivalence checks and various forms of formal verification, but doing that in great detail may be more specific to ASIC than FPGA design. The VUnit mentioned in the comment by Briand Drummond looks very interesting.

Note that hardware engineers tend to call checks on VHDL code *verification*, where *testing* is what you do on a physical product. I've had one professor that was very passionate about the distinction.